# Add space between 2 connected nodes

Tags: graphviz, dot

I would like to add a little more horizontal space between the 2 nodes so the edge labels appear associated to their node (instead of in the middle of the edge):

[image]

The [graphviz source](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%7B%0A%20%20rankdir%3D%22LR%22%3B%0A%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dcylinder%5D%0A%20%20clone%0A%20%20initial%0A%20%20clone%20-%3E%20initial%20%5Bheadlabel%3D%22origin%22%2Ctaillabel%3D%22clone%22%5D%0A%7D%0A):

```
digraph {
  rankdir="LR";
  node [shape=cylinder]
  clone
  initial
  clone -> initial [headlabel="origin",taillabel="clone"]
}
```

Expected:
[image]

I tried using [nodesep](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/nodesep/) but it seems to only work when there are no edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**nodesep** was a good try, but your ranking is LR, so **ranksep** is the way to go

```
digraph {
  rankdir="LR";
  ranksep=1.2 // rank-to-rank in inches
  node [shape=cylinder]
  clone
  initial
  clone -> initial [headlabel="origin",taillabel="clone"]
}
```

Giving:
[image]